# Contact form 7 - how can i catch and customize each checkbox?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, checkbox, contact-form-7

how can i catch and customize each checkbox in Contact form 7 plugin?

i have a list of checkboxes in a single field.

what i'm trying to do is to add an attribute and value using jQuery to each checkbox.

like this:

```
$("input['type=checkbox']:nth-child(3)").attr("data-price", 500).addClass("cf7-checkbox");
```

this is my html code:

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap list-tosafot1">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox" id="options1st">
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
            <input type="checkbox" name="list-tosafot1[]" value="price-100" />&nbsp;
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Checkbox1 - price 100</span>
        </span>
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
            <input type="checkbox" name="list-tosafot1[]" value="price-200" />&nbsp;
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Checkbox2 - price 200</span>
        </span>
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
            <input type="checkbox" name="list-tosafot1[]" value="price-300" />&nbsp;
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Checkbox3 - price 300</span>
        </span>
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
            <input type="checkbox" name="list-tosafot1[]" value="price-400" />&nbsp;
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Checkbox4 - price 400</span>
        </span>
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item last">
            <input type="checkbox" name="list-tosafot1[]" value="price-500" />&nbsp;
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Checkbox5 - price 500</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

thanks so much!!!

Comment: Have the checkboxes got an id?

Comment: Please add more info, are you getting any errors, it's not working. Also add a piece of code so we can check what's happening. Thanks.

Comment: I think the way you're trying to select the checkbox in jQuery is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selector shouldn't work because the input elements don't share the same parent.

```
$("input['type=checkbox']:nth-child(3)").attr("data-price", 500).addClass("cf7-checkbox");
```

So I found this solution:

```
$('.wpcf7-checkbox .wpcf7-list-item:nth-child(3) input').attr("data-price", 500).addClass("cf7-checkbox");
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're trying to select the checkboxes is probably wrong, here is a way to loop through all checkboxes:

```
var type = null;
$("input").each(function()
{
  type = $(this).attr("type");
  if(type == "checkbox")
  {
    $(this).attr("data-price", 500);
    $(this).addClass("cf7-checkbox");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! but I have many of different values each checkbox. about 10 checkboxes.

Comment: Are there checkboxes with the same value?

Comment: So you only need to change certain ones?